# Why is blogger linking my new pages to the home page?

Tags: blogger

Here is the link to my blog: [Click me](http://bmcc-ptk.blogspot.com/)

I am not the owner of this blog and this is my first time working with Blogger
All I did was create a new page and threw some code I copied off a website

If you notice, Gallery and Home are both highlighted on default, and they both lead to the same directory. When I try to just preview gallery from my pages, it shows up fine.

The problem isn't with the copied code because this happens any time I try to make a page, despite what is in the code.

I found the problem in the source code of the website, but I don't know how to edit it.

```
<ul>
<li class='selected'><a href='http://bmcc-ptk.blogspot.com/'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='http://bmcc-ptk.blogspot.com/p/events-and-announcements.html'>Announcements</a></li>
<li><a href='http://bmcc-ptk.blogspot.com/p/minutes.html'>Minutes</a></li>
<li><a href='http://bmcc-ptk.blogspot.com/p/contact_09.html'>Contacts and Useful Links</a></li>
<li><a href='http://bmcc-ptk.blogspot.com/p/survey.html'>Survey</a></li>
<li class='selected'><a href='http://bmcc-ptk.blogspot.com/'>Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions or ideas that you provide is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sign in to blogger

CLick on your bog name

go to layout

you should see a square named "pages",click on edit ....

if the above solution does not work.

then go to blogger
then go to "pages" tab"(below posts) and try editing

if you are unable to get  what i wrote,just msg me back,i will show you via images.